Dynamic table chain refresh in snowflake using dbt
I have 2 views, a dynamic table A is build on top of these 2 views in downstream target_lag.
I have another dynamic table B which references both views and dynamic table A in target_lag = '4 hours'.
When I run dbt run -m dynamic table B, it first refreshes dynamic table A then B, what I want is just to refresh dynamic table B not A.
What do I need to change?

You would need to remove from Table A TARGET_LAG = DOWNSTREAM
